# psql to csv file '-' becomes '-0'

Tags: csv, awk, openoffice-calc, psql

I want to output the results from a psql query to a csv file. I have used the following approach

```
\o test.csv
SELECT myo_date, myo_maps_study, cbp_lvef, cbp_rvef, myx_ecg_posneg, myx_st, std_drugs, std_reason_comment FROM myo INNER JOIN studies ON (myo_std_uid = std_uid) LEFT OUTER JOIN cbp on (std_uid = cbp_std_uid) LEFT OUTER JOIN myx on (std_uid = myx_std_uid) WHERE myo_maps_study ~ 'MYO[0-9]*\$' AND std_reason_comment ~ 'AF' AND cbp_lvef is not null AND myx_st IS NOT NULL AND std_drugs IS NOT NULL ORDER by myo_date DESC LIMIT 500;
\q
```

The results on the query on its own is as follows

```
06/11/2013 | MYO134537      | 36.75000 | 29.00000 | -              |    0.0 | ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;LISINOPRIL;METFORMIN;PPI;STATIN;FLUOXETINE;AMLODIPINE;GTN     | CPOE;AF;T2DM;POSET
 31/10/2013 | MYO130555      | 45.00000 | 36.25000 | -              |    0.0 | DILTIAZEM;STATIN;LISINOPRIL;ASPIRIN;FRUSEMIDE;SALBUTAMOL;PARACETAMOL;AMOXICILLIN | TROP-VE; CP; AF; CTPA-VE; ANT T; INV; RF
 23/10/2013 | MYO130538      | 18.75000 | 18.50000 | +              |   -1.0 | ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;RAMIPRIL                                                      | AF;MR;QLVFN;FAILED CARDIOVERSION
 18/10/2013 | MYO134510      | 39.50000 | 32.25000 | -              |    0.0 | ASPIRIN;STATIN;CO-CODAMOL;BISOPROLOL;GTN;PPI                                     | PVD;AF
 18/10/2013 | MYO130537      | 19.00000 | 18.00000 | -              |    0.0 | STATIN;RAMIPRIL;AMLODIPINE;WARFARIN;(METOPROLOL-STOPPED FOR TEST)                | TIA;AF;RF+++;ETINAP
```

However the csv file (opened in open office) looks like this

```
06/11/2013  MYO134537   36.75   29  -0  0   ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;LISINOPRIL;METFORMIN;PPI;STATIN;FLUOXETINE;AMLODIPINE;GTN    CPOE;AF;T2DM;POSET
31/10/2013  MYO130555   45  36.25   -0  0   DILTIAZEM;STATIN;LISINOPRIL;ASPIRIN;FRUSEMIDE;SALBUTAMOL;PARACETAMOL;AMOXICILLIN    TROP-VE; CP; AF; CTPA-VE; ANT T; INV; RF
23/10/2013  MYO130538   18.75   18.5    0   -1  ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;RAMIPRIL AF;MR;QLVFN;FAILED CARDIOVERSION
18/10/2013  MYO134510   39.5    32.25   -0  0   ASPIRIN;STATIN;CO-CODAMOL;BISOPROLOL;GTN;PPI    PVD;AF
18/10/2013  MYO130537   19  18  -0  0   STATIN;RAMIPRIL;AMLODIPINE;WARFARIN;(METOPROLOL-STOPPED FOR TEST)   TIA;AF;RF+++;ETINAP
```

The '-' signs have become -0 and '+' have become 0. For clarity, I would like to change these to N and P respectively.

Doing a `more test.csv` gives

```
06/11/2013,MYO134537,36.75,29,-0,0,ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;LISINOPRIL;METFORMIN;PPI;STATIN;FLUOXETINE;AMLODIPINE;GTN,CPOE;AF;T2DM;POSET,,
31/10/2013,MYO130555,45,36.25,-0,0,DILTIAZEM;STATIN;LISINOPRIL;ASPIRIN;FRUSEMIDE;SALBUTAMOL;PARACETAMOL;AMOXICILLIN,TROP-VE; CP; AF; CTPA-VE; ANT T; INV; RF,,
23/10/2013,MYO130538,18.75,18.5,0,-1,ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;RAMIPRIL,AF;MR;QLVFN;FAILED CARDIOVERSION,,
18/10/2013,MYO134510,39.5,32.25,-0,0,ASPIRIN;STATIN;CO-CODAMOL;BISOPROLOL;GTN;PPI,PVD;AF,,
18/10/2013,MYO130537,19,18,-0,0,STATIN;RAMIPRIL;AMLODIPINE;WARFARIN;(METOPROLOL-STOPPED FOR TEST),TIA;AF;RF+++;ETINAP,,
```

However, when I select the cell in open office the contents of -0 or 0 cells is always 0. This does not allow me to do a search a replace. I do not want to change these manually.

Can I force the + and - through using a psql command or can I use some other linux tool to change the -0 to N and 0 to P. I am using RHEL6.

Comment: You say your fields become zeros in Open Office, but that just means that you imported the fields incorrectly. Have you tried changing the field from numeric to string?

Comment: @TLP You are correct as I see + and - in the Text Import preview screen. However changing field from numeric to string (text) has no impact

Comment: Sounds like it has already changed `-` to `-0` at that stage, so you would need to find a way to import it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [decode function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) in place of the field name.

```
decode(myx_ecg_posneg,'-','N','+','P')
```

Update: Sorry, that's pl/sql.  Try the case expression:

```
CASE myx_ecg_posneg
WHEN '-' THEN 'N'
WHEN '+' THEN 'P'
END
```

Comment: The field myx_ecg_posneg are of type charachter and I get the following error `ERROR:  function decode(character, "unknown", "unknown") does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`